# Nugget - how to link the SFML library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, nuget-package

I haven't used C++ or Visual Studio in a long time.

I want to use them again, and figured I may as well try to use a package manager, after seeing how useful managers are from other languages.

I created a new empty project, and installed the SFML library using Nugget, however it doesn't seem to handle linking in any way.
I can #include the SFML header files, but the linker complains about unresovled references.

For the time being I linked the required files manually, even though Visual Studio recognizes that they are installed, and offers to select between dynamic and static linking in the project settings under "Referenced Packages".

This means that I need to write this kind of text, and other variations for each build type:

```
$(SolutionDir)packages\sfml_graphics.2.5.1\build\native\lib\Win32\v141\Debug\static\sfml-graphics-s-d.lib
$(SolutionDir)packages\sfml_system.2.5.1\build\native\lib\Win32\v141\Debug\static\sfml-system-s-d.lib
$(SolutionDir)packages\sfml_system.2.5.1\build\native\lib\Win32\v141\freetype.lib
$(SolutionDir)packages\sfml_window.2.5.1\build\native\lib\Win32\v141\Debug\static\sfml-window-s-d.lib
```

I was under the impression the point of using a package manager would be that it handles the linking automatically, especially when changing targets and configurations.

Am I mistaken? because if I am, it seems like downloading the package directly from its website would be simpler, as it won't be spread over many folders with such long paths.

In addition, is it supposed to handle DLLs if I were to use dynamic linking, or am I still to this day supposed to copy them manually to the executable's folder? (when developing, that is)